# Create .bat to recursively delete subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

I am working to migrate from Drivebender to Drivepool. If not familiar, these are duplication softwares, but function differently. Drivebender has primary and secondary files, and Drivepool does not.

Anyways, I am attempting to clean up the folders left behind after migration. Drivebender creates folders named "FOLDER.DUPLICATE.$DRIVEBENDER". I am trying to create a .bat script that will remove all of these folders. I keep getting "Access is Denied" when attempting to run what I have below. Any suggestions?

```
@echo off
for /r %%f in (FOLDER.DUPLICATE.$DRIVEBENDER) do if exist %%f (
  echo %%f
  rd "%%f"
)
```

Comment: I find batch scripting to be obscure, so no comments on that portion. But, possibly silly, question: Do you receive the same error when running the batch file as admin? I am assuming the backup files have different permissions for security purposes.

Comment: When you need to remove the folder recursively then simply use `rd /s folder_to_remove`. And FOR not needed - at all.

Comment: Run the batch file with admin permissions, perhaps? There also may be issues with who owns the folder or if a process (ex. a service) is using the folder.

Comment: *I keep getting "Access is Denied"* If so then you have no needed permissions in the filesystem for some folder or file deletion. You must add according permissions to your account, or run your command/script as administrator.

Comment: @echo off
    for /r %%f in (FOLDER.DUPLICATE.$DRIVEBENDER) do if exist %%f echo rd /s /q "%%f"

Comment: @JG7 It was something where I did takeown to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /r %%f in (FOLDER.DUPLICATE.$DRIVEBENDER) do if exist "%%f" echo rd /s /q "%%f"
:: PLEASE NOTE THE ECHO BEFORE THE RD COMMAND.  
:: DELETE IT ONCE YOU ARE SURE IT IS DOING WHAT YOU WANT.
```

This works for me.  ***If I was having problems taking those folders after knowing the above script works***, I would use the `takeown` utility and or the `CACLS` utulity that comes with windows and would be careful to only touch the permissions on those folders.

Comment: This *kind of* works, but the problem is that I am running into the MAX_PATH limitation of CMD. No longer running into permissions problems, (I had actually used takeown prior to your suggestion after thinking about it.). Maybe I need to use powershell to get around this MAX_PATH issue?

Comment: @JasonDeFuria .. I am so sorry to hear that.. all bets are off after clearing the MAX_PATH crap.  MANY MANY programmers still use "MAX_PATH" in their code even though it is no longer a thing.  Personally, I do everything in my power to keep the paths shorter but not always under my control when pulling from a git branch or similar.

Comment: Prepend non legal paths with `\\?\ `. EG `\\?\C:\Windows\System32`. This lets Windows know your program can handle paths up to 32K. CMD can handle paths that long.

Comment: On second thought .. you can probably use the `subst` command to get around this.. sometimes it works.. sometimes it doesn't.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst